# Div is not fully centered in the middle of the page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, turnjs

I am using turnjs to create a flipbook inside the webpage and I want to center it right in the middle. This is how the webpage looks like now : https://i.stack.imgur.com/90Hyh.jpg .

This is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/turn.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/test.css" />
</head>
<body>

<div class="flipbook-viewport">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="flipbook">
            <div style="background-image:url(brochure/Brochure_Main.jpeg)"></div>
            <div style="background-image:url(brochure/Brochure_Mobile_Ordering.jpg)"></div>
      <div style="background-image:url(brochure/Brochure_POS_Automobile.jpg)"></div>
            <div style="background-image:url(brochure/Brochure_POS_Beauty_Wellness.jpg)"></div>
            <div style="background-image:url(brochure/Brochure_POS_Food_Beverage.jpg)"></div>
            <div style="background-image:url(brochure/Brochure_POS_Hair_Salon.jpg)"></div>
            <div style="background-image:url(brochure/Brochure_POS_Minimart.jpg)"></div>
            <div style="background-image:url(brochure/Brochure_POS_Mobile_Phone_Shop.jpg)"></div>
            <div style="background-image:url(brochure/Brochure_POS_Retail.jpg)"></div>
            <div style="background-image:url(brochure/Brochure_POS_Wholesale.jpg)"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="buttons">
                          <button type="button" onclick="thePreviousPage()" class="button">Previous</button>
              <button type="button" onclick="theHomePage()" class="button">Home</button>
                          <button type="button" onclick="theNextPage()" class="button">Next</button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    // Create the flipbook

  $('.flipbook').turn({

            // Elevation

            elevation: 50,

            // Enable gradients

            gradients: true,

            // Auto center this flipbook

            autoCenter: true

    });

  function thePreviousPage()
  {
    $('.flipbook').turn('previous');
  }

  function theHomePage()
  {
    $('.flipbook').turn('page',1);
  }

  function theNextPage()
  {
    $('.flipbook').turn('next');
  }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the css:

```
body{
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:#fcfcfc;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.flipbook-viewport{
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
  margin-right: -50%;
}

.flipbook-viewport .container{
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  height: 90%;
  width: 90%;
}

.flipbook-viewport .flipbook{
    width:90%;
    height:90%;
  top: -50%;
  left: -50%;
}

.flipbook
{
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.flipbook-viewport .page{
    width:461px;
    height:600px;
    background-color:white;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:100% 100%;
}

.flipbook .page{
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -ms-box-shadow:0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -o-box-shadow:0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow:0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.flipbook-viewport .page img{
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    margin:0;
}

.flipbook-viewport .shadow{
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-box-shadow 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-box-shadow 0.5s;
    -o-transition: -webkit-box-shadow 0.5s;
    -ms-transition: -ms-box-shadow 0.5s;

    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 20px #ccc;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 20px #ccc;
    -o-box-shadow:0 0 20px #ccc;
    -ms-box-shadow:0 0 20px #ccc;
    box-shadow:0 0 20px #ccc;
}

.button{
  position: relative;
    align-items: center;
}
```

I have tried using flexbox, justify content center but the flipbook will still not be fully centered.

This is the docs for turnjs: http://www.turnjs.com/turnjs4-api-docs.pdf .

Is there anyway to center the div so that it will be in the middle of webpage?

Comment: Show us your `display:flex;` attempt. Inline style *(HTML style attribute or JavaScript Element.style)* overrides CSS, and it's a bad practice to use it in HTML. If you want to change the style you would have to edit every one of those Elements, since the style is inline, creating unnecessary work for anyone working on the site later.

Comment: Also, please provide valid images. All the image URLs in your example are broken.

Comment: This is when I added flex into the body :https://imgur.com/a/zqhsfC4 . 
I changed the body to  `body{
 overflow:hidden;
 background-color:#fcfcfc;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your CSS codes to this:

```
body{
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:#fcfcfc;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.flipbook-viewport{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

.flipbook-viewport .container{
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.flipbook-viewport .container .flipbook{
  width:90% !important;
  height:100% !important;
  margin:auto !important;
  position: relative !important;
}

.flipbook-viewport .container .flipbook .turn-page-wrapper{
  margin:auto !important;
  position: relative !important;
}

.flipbook-viewport .turn-page-wrapper{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:white;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:100% 100%;
}

.flipbook .turn-page-wrapper{
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -ms-box-shadow:0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -o-box-shadow:0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow:0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  position: relative;
}

.flipbook-viewport .turn-page-wrapper img{
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    margin:0;
}

.flipbook-viewport .shadow{
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-box-shadow 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-box-shadow 0.5s;
    -o-transition: -webkit-box-shadow 0.5s;
    -ms-transition: -ms-box-shadow 0.5s;

    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 20px #ccc;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 20px #ccc;
    -o-box-shadow:0 0 20px #ccc;
    -ms-box-shadow:0 0 20px #ccc;
    box-shadow:0 0 20px #ccc;
}

.button{
  position: relative;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just try

```
.flipbook-viewport .container{
    // ...
    margin: 0 auto;
    // ...
}
```